# Counting unique nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list, like

```
list1 = [['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato'], ['apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'banana'], ['orange', 'tomato', 'banana', 'apple'], ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato'], ['apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'banana']]
```

how do I calculate the unique quantity? In this case, there are 3 unique nested lists: ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato'],
['apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'banana'],
['orange', 'tomato', 'banana', 'apple']

In fact, the length of the nested list will be from two to three thousand

Answer (score 6):

If you convert each list to a `tuple`, you can put them all in a `set` which automatically eliminates the duplicates:

```
>>> {tuple(fruits) for fruits in list1}
{('orange', 'tomato', 'banana', 'apple'), ('apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'banana'), ('banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato')}
```

If you want to get that back into the list-of-lists form:

```
>>> [list(fruits) for fruits in {tuple(fruits) for fruits in list1}]
[['orange', 'tomato', 'banana', 'apple'], ['apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'banana'], ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato']]
```

Comment: `list(map(list, {...}))` would be more concise for the 2nd case.

Comment: Every time I use `map` in an answer, someone pops up to complain about it.

Comment: And I guess `set(map(tuple, list1))` for the first. But that's a question of preference.